# T-SQL Store Prodecure execution Issue One Input paramater (default value) and One Output parameter

Tags: t-sql

I've create a store procedure with an input parameter with a default value and an output parameter, however I can't execute it, without receiving an error message:

> Msg 8162, Level 16, State 2, Procedure spGetEmployeeCountDefault, Line 21
>   The formal parameter "@Gender" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output.

Definition of store procedure and how I'm trying to execute it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetEmployeeCountDefault
(
 @Gender nchar(1) = 'F', -- Supply Gender Value e.g. 'M' or 'F'
 @EmployeeCount int Output  -- Return an Integer Value for Employee Count
)
AS

BEGIN
    -- Main SP Code to retrieve the count 
    SELECT @EmployeeCount = COUNT([BusinessEntityID]) 
    FROM  [HumanResources].[Employee]
    WHERE Gender = @Gender
END

-- Execute store procedure and select result
DECLARE @EmployeeCount int
EXEC spGetEmployeeCountDefault @EmployeeCount out 
SELECT @EmployeeCount [Total of Employes]
```

Is the definition correct, can a store procedure be used in this way, thanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't explicitly name parameters, i.e.

```
EXECUTE spGetEmployeeCountDefault @EmployeeCount = @EmployeeCount OUT;
```

Then SQL Server will assign them in the order they are stated in the create procedure statement, so what you really have is the equivalent of:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeCount int

EXECUTE spGetEmployeeCountDefault @Gender = @EmployeeCount OUT;
```

Which is what is causing the problem. So you either need to explicitly name your parameters as above, or pass in a value for @Gender:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeCount int

EXECUTE spGetEmployeeCountDefault NULL, @EmployeeCount OUT;
```